# interfaces in oop, "java-like" and "c++-like"

Tags: java, c++, oop

In C++ it is common practice to only define methods in the class-body and to implement them in an source file.

But this is not really an interface. Because only the class can implement the methods.

In Java one can define an "interface" just as you could define a class. Now any class can implement the defined interface.

Now imagine the following, when programming in Java. I have a class "administration" and another which is called "contact". The "administration" class contains an array of "contact"-objects. Now there shall be defined and implemented some useful methods as "add", "delete", "swap", etc.. to operate on the "contact"-array.

Those methods should be defined by an interface and implemented by the "administration" class.

My question is, should the Interface be referred to the "customer" class, so for example we call it ICustomer, or should it be referred to the "administration" class, which yields "IAdministration".

I don't mind about "foo-able" or "I-foo", just about the concept which is behind interfaces?

Should they be oriented by the class which describes the data ("contact") or the class which handles the data ("administration")?

I know it's a more philosophical question, but anyway i would like to know your opinion on that.

Regards

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Interfaces can be oriented to any type of class.
Implicitly/Informally each class has some interface
determined by the methods that class defines.

It should be IAdministration in your sense. Because it
defines operations on a `administration` which is a
container for `contact` objects (backed by an array in your words).

The "add", "delete", "swap" are not operations of a `contact`
object, it seems, but on an `administration` object.

ICustomer/IContact would be another interface which would have
methods like e.g. setFirstName, setLastName, setPhone,
getFirstName, getLastName, getPhone etc. It is just some POJO/bean
carrying some data. So it seems to me from your description.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the quick answer. That clarified the situation for me.

Answer (score 2):

What the term "interface" means (and what the therm "Object" means) depends on the programming paradigm you are refferring.

Java embrace totally the classic OOP paradigm, based on inheritance of a base and some interfaces.

C++, by converse, can support "mutiple inheritance" that is a more general concept.
An "interface", in this context can be seen as a class with only pure virtual methods;

```
class Ia
{
public:
     virtual int method1()=0;
     virtual int method2()=0;
     virtual ~Ia() {}
};

class Ib
{
public:
     vritual int method3()=0;
     vritual int method4()=0;
     virtual ~Ib() {}
};

class Object
{
public:
    virtual ~Object() {}
};

class A:
   public Object,
   public Ia,
{
public:
     virtual int method1(); //implementation 
     virtual int method2(); //implementation 
};

class B:
   public A,
   public Ib
{
public:
     virtual int method3(); //implementation 
     virtual int method4(); //implementation 
};
```

It should be easy in this sense to recognize your case

Comment: Thanks a lot for the answer and the demonstration.

Answer (score 1):

I cannot really follow your example, but I believe the confusion might be arising from the different uses and meanings of the same term.

In general, the interface to system is how external parts can interact with that. This is used often in code stating that this class offers this and that function in its *interface*.

A different concept is that of the OO-Interface, which is really a protocol to interact with a type. In different languages, *interface* is used to refer to the protocol, or to an *abstract interface*.

You should embrace both uses of the term, as both are common. In C++ a class might implement a protocol (stateless pure abstract classes are equivalent to interfaces) and thus implement that *interface*, and it might have those and other functions which define its own *interface*.

Comment: Thats true, for example in Object-Pascal a class is defined inside a region wich is also called "interface". Maybe a third possibility, how the term "interface" is used.

Nevertheless i found it confusing that an OO-Interface is some kind of "defined interacting of two components" because it only delivers the method-definitions.

But in the end it's just a way of _definiton_. Thanks a lot for the answer.

Comment: @user3272529: in C++ terms, those are not *definitions*, but *declarations*. It *declares* that the functions exist, but does not provide a *definition* for them.